# Number of occurences of a number in all the queries?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, stl

Take an unsorted array like:

> 4,5,1,2,3,7,8,3

and queries be like:

> [1 2] [5 5] [2 6] [6 6] [1 6] [1 5]

where each query represents a interval of indices.

Length of array and total queries can be upto **100000**.

I want to calculate the number of occurences of every index in each of the queries like below:

> occurences of 1: 3
>
> occurences of 3: 3
>
> occurences of 5: 4, etc

Any optimal way to perform this ? I have tried in naive way but need some hints for optimal solution.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: what is array length? how many query is there? if you find way to large range array and query u can solve it by using BIT

Comment: Kindly show us what you have done so far so that we can help you

Comment: @Garrick is your array value change by query?

Comment: @GolamMazidSajib Can u elaborate ?

Comment: What is the actual problem you want to solve? If there's an unsorted array, you probably not just want to count indices, do you?

Comment: why occurances of 3 is 3? i think it will be 4 .. cause 3 index is 5.. it will exist in 5-5, 2-6,1-6,1-5 queries

Comment: @GolamMazidSajib index 3(not element at index 3) occurs only in interval of 3 queries, that you mentioned except [5 5]

Comment: @idmean, it is a part of a problem and this part i want to optimize.

Comment: @GolamMazidSajib Can you help with logic ?

Comment: @Garrick updated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by [BIT](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/binary-indexed-tree-or-fenwick-tree/)(binary index tree) or [Segment-Tree](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/segment_tree.html)..

I attached two link there to learn about those algoritm...

**BIT solution:**

For each query lets range: `[l r]` :

- Now you need to update in BIT `l to n` with value `1`.
- Now you need to exclude update `r+1 to n`...so update `r+1 to n` with
  value `-1` in BIT..

Each update operation take log(n) in BIT...

Calculate number of occurances for each index:

```
Call sum(index) in BIT to get count
```

This operation take log(n) time..

**Complexity:**

complexity of this solution: `Q*(log(n)+log(n)) + N *(log(n))`..

**Code:**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int tree[100005], A[100005];

void update(int idx, int n, int v) {
    while (idx <= n) {
        tree[idx] += v;
        idx += (idx & -idx);
    }
}

int sum(int idx) {
    int res = 0;
    while (idx) {
        res += tree[idx];
        idx -= (idx & -idx);
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    int n, q, i, l, r;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    }
    scanf("%d", &q);
    memset(tree, 0, sizeof(tree));
    while (q--) {
        scanf("%d%d", &l, &r);
        update(l,n,1);
        update(r+1,n,-1);
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", sum(i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```